# Bootstrap-datepicker changeMonth

Tags: javascript

Использую  [bootstrap-datepicker](http://goo.gl/l1Ds16)

И при таких настройках

```
<input type="text" type="text" class="form-control">

$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm",
    startView: 1,
    minViewMode: 1,
    language: "ru",
    autoclose: true
});
```

Не могу понять, как при выборе месяца выполнить какое-нибудь действие с помощью js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('create_time').onchange = function () {
            window.location.search = "readmin&from_date=" + this.value;
        };
    };
</script>
```

где create_time - id строки с datepicker